# Can I use a JDBC driver for Application failover to the correct Oracle DB instance (Data Guard, not RAC cluster)

Tags: database, oracle, failover

Can I use a driver for Application failover to the correct Oracle DB instance  (Data Guard, not RAC cluster)

The documentation seems to suggest I can with a RAC cluster, I am not sure if I can with Data Guard Primary and Standby instance.  I want to do this to avoid sing a GSLB

But I do not have a RAC, I have a Data Guard primary and Standby instance.  Can I use a JDBC driver for this ?

Answer (score 1):

We use the DataGuard in the following configuration.
Connection string for jdbc.

```
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (FAILOVER=ON) 
    (LOAD_BALANCE=off)  
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.xx.yyy.88)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.xx.yyy.89)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = D88.XXX.YYY.ZZZ)
      (FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=select)(METHOD=basic))
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
  )
```

The trigger creates a service when the database starts in the primary mode.
Clients are connected by the name of the service, which is created in the trigger at the start of the database, and not by the default database name or service.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sys.set_svc_name
 AFTER
  STARTUP
 ON DATABASE
DECLARE role VARCHAR(30);
BEGIN

SELECT Database_Role
INTO Role
FROM V$database;
IF Role = 'PRIMARY' THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter system set service_names=''d88.XXX.YYY.ZZZ'' scope=memory'; END IF;

END;
```

Comment: I see how you are describing the DB failover, but I do not understand how the client fails over to the correct DB

Comment: Can the client application use a JDBC driver in which to put both the IP of the primary and standby on the application side, so that when the primary is not reachable, it can easily switch to the standby ?

Comment: Yes just use an address_list in your JDBC URL. The driver will automatically switch to the second address if the first isn't responding. You can also configure a number of retries and delay between retries in order to avoid connecting to DG during a temp network outage.